# Chrome toDataURI bug

Tags: google-chrome, data-uri

Until a day or so ago, the Canvas2Image JS library and .toDataURI JS method worked in Chrome. http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ Now, with Chrome version 19.0.1084.46, if you try clicking Save PNG on the referenced page to download a PNG version of the HTML5 canvas element, it doesn't prompt a download - but generates a MIME type error. Is this intentional - perhaps for security reasons, or a bug? (It continues to work in Firefox.)

Comment: Seems to be working here, using version 20.0.1132.11 (Build 137611) dev-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Google Chrome v19 as it works fine in v18 and v20. I'm sure it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if it's intentional, and not a bug. Even past Chrome 20, right-click and save doesn't detect the file type as PNG. It's perfectly happy to let the user download without a proper file extension. Prior to Chrome 19, I think it appended .png.