# PHP inline PDF output in Google Chrome - issue with PDFs above 150k

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf

I'm not able to inline output PDFs bigger than 150k in Google Chrome using default PDF Viewer plugin and PHP code below

```
$size = filesize($file_fullpath);
$begin = 0;
$end = $size;

header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
header("Content-Type: $mimeType");
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:' . ($end - $begin));
header("Content-Range: bytes $begin-$end/$size");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$filename'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header("Last-Modified: $time");
header('Connection: close');

$cur = $begin;
fseek($fm, $begin, 0);

while (!feof($fm) && $cur < $end && (connection_status() == 0)) {
   print fread($fm, min(1024 * 16, $end - $cur));
   $cur+= 1024 * 16;

}
```

All work fine with FireFox or Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got issue resolved. It looks like default Google Chrome PDF Viewer plugin doesn't like it how does the data are "served" and it looks like simplified code below works fine

```
header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Type: $mimeType");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$filename'");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length:' . filesize($file_fullpath));

// output the file first clean mem
ob_clean();
flush();

while (!feof($fm)) {
   $mem_chunks = fread($fm, 1024);
   print $mem_chunks;
}

exit;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the final solution!

Answer (score 0):

That was an issue with some previous versions of Google Chrome (49.xx versions) for both Windows and Mac OS X, x86 and x64 versions but it was fixed in latest versions. It is a bug that [was re-introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662601/chrome-todatauri-bug).

So check if you are using the very latest versions of Google Chrome.

UPDATE (April 8, 2016):

- v.42 of Google Chrome was silently failing with datauri in the adress bar with data larger than 128KB (base64 encoded data)
- v.49 (as reported in comments) fails at datauri larger than about 150KB

Comment: My Chrome is up to date and I have tested 5 other computers including OSX - all have same problem

Comment: I've tested with this inline file (164kb) https://s3.amazonaws.com/bytescout.com/files/help/BytescoutPDFGeneratorSDKJS/add-image-from-url/sample.html in 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) and it works OK

Comment: @JackTheKnife but I've faced the similar issue as you have described with previous versions (tested on different platforms) and the limitation was 128kb. Then it was fixed in next versions.

Comment: That one works fine for me but it is 124k (two images only sample PDF) and my Chrome is 49.0.2623.112 m

Comment: @JackTheKnife the file is 124K but the datauri data length is 164KB (as base64 increases the size of transimitted data). I've checked my records: the issue with this particular file not working was with v.42 of Google Chrome.

Comment: Then v.49 is getting chocked with slightly bigger datauri length than 164KB if the file site is grater than 150K